# Hash anchor links fail to find/target ID DOM element target (in certain circumstances)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hash anchor links fail to find/target ID DOM element target (and therefore fail to trigger JS UI tab change)

Hi visit https://eurosurveillance.org/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES.2019.24.40.1900157 and scroll down the HTML fulltext (shown in this tab) and try clicking on the link marked 'Supplement 1' or 'Supplement 2' note nothing happens.

There is nothing clever about the links they are normal html hash links....

```html
<a href="/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES.2019.24.40.1900157#supplementary_data">Supplement 1</a>
```

Now if you visit the same page but this time do a hard reload with the following URL in the browser address bar https://eurosurveillance.org/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES.2019.24.40.1900157#html_fulltext (notice the only change is the hash in the URL). Now try following the same instructions as before and you will notice that for some reason the anchor link is now followed and the anchor tab JS is triggered this is behaviour that I am expecting

Please advise. thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like the page inspects the hash onload and does stuff. you should do the same things in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange as in onload/ready/whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Hi many thanks the issue was resolved by refactoring the responsive-tabs.js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        //responsive tabs API code.
    var Tabs = {

          init: function() {
            this.bindUIfunctions();
            this.pageLoadCorrectTab();
          },

          bindUIfunctions: function() {

            // Delegation
            $(document)
              .on("click", ".js-transformer-tabs a[href^='#']:not('.active, .disabled')", function(event) {
                Tabs.changeTab(this.hash);
                event.preventDefault();
              })
              .on("click", ".js-transformer-tabs a.active, .js-transformer-tabs a.disabled", function(event) {
                Tabs.toggleMobileMenu(event, this);
                event.preventDefault();
              })
             .on("click", ".js-textoptionsFulltext a.html:not('.disabled')", function(event) {      
                    //console.log("tab?" + this.hash);
                    event.preventBubble=true;
                     var anchorTab = Tabs.changeTab(this.hash);
                     anchorTab.trigger("click"); //trigger click event in this case it will be html fulltext.
                    //event.preventDefault();        
                });
             //We also need to handle the back state by telling the browser to trigger the tab behaviour!   
            $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
               anchor = $('[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]');
               if (anchor.length >  0) {
                   Tabs.displayTab(anchor);
               } else {
                  var defaultAnchor =  $('.js-transformer-tabs li.active a');
                  if (defaultAnchor) {
                      Tabs.displayTab(defaultAnchor)
                  }
               }
            });
            
          },

          changeTab: function(hash) {
             
            var anchor = $(".js-transformer-tabs a[href='" + hash + "']");
            var activeTab = anchor.find('span strong');
            Tabs.displayTab(anchor);

            $(".js-dropdown li").hide();
             
            $(".js-mobile-tab").text($(activeTab).text());
                
            // update history stack adding additional history entries.
            // pushState is supported!
            history.pushState(null, null,  hash);

            // Close menu, in case mobile
            return anchor; // make property available outside the function

          },
          pageLoadCorrectTab: function() {
              //console.log("document.location.hash: " + document.location.hash);
            if   (document.location.hash.length > 0) {
                // If the page has a hash on load, go to that tab
                 var anchor = $(".js-transformer-tabs a[href='" + document.location.hash + "']");
                 if (!anchor.hasClass("disabled")) {
                     var anchorTab = this.changeTab(document.location.hash);
                     // this is a further amendment to allow the fulltext and 
                     //(any future event if its attached) to load when bookmarking a page with a particular tab. 
                     anchorTab.trigger("click");
                 }
              } else if ($(".js-transformer-tabs .active.tabIcon .active").length > 0) {
                  // go to which ever tab is defined as active in the JSP page and trigger a click on it 
                  // but, only when no hash in the url
                  var activeTab = $(".js-transformer-tabs .active.tabIcon .active");  
                      activeTab.trigger("click"); //trigger click
              }
          },

          toggleMobileMenu: function(event, el) {
            $(el).closest("ul").toggleClass("open");
          },
          displayTab: function(anchortab) {
                var url = anchortab.attr("href");
                //console.log("url" + url);
                var divtabContent = $(url);
                
                // activate correct anchor (visually)
                anchortab.addClass("active").parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");

                // activate correct div (visually)
                divtabContent.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            }

    }


    Modernizr.load([{
    //test
    test : Modernizr.history,
        //if yes then do nothing as nothing extra needs loading....
        
        //if no then we need to load the history API via AJAX
    nope : ['/js/' + ingentaCMSApp.instanceprefix + '/vendor/history.min.js'],
        
    complete : function() {
        
        var location = window.history.location || window.location; 
            Tabs.init();
    }

    }])
    

  });

    //end of responsive tabs API code.
    



    $(".js-select").click(function(){
        $(".js-dropdown li").slideToggle();
    });
```